# Explicit specification of Arraylists

Tags: java, list, arraylist, java-7

Is the explicit specification of array lists considered as a bad practice since Java7? Why is it unneccessary from this version?

```
List<String> foo = new Arraylist<String>(); // before
List<String> bar = new Arraylist<>(); // from Java7
```

Is it just because it's defined in the List?
Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is the explicit specification of array lists considered as a bad practice since Java7?

It's not "bad practice" - it's just a little more longwinded than it might be. The two statements have exactly the same effect, so there's no downside to the longer version in that sense. You definitely don't need to go around "fixing" all your old code - but you may choose to use the shorter form when you're editing existing code anyway, or writing new code.

> Why is it unneccessary from this version?

Because Java 7 introduced the "diamond operator" (not actually an operator at all) precisely to avoid having to specify type arguments redundantly. From the [Oracle documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/language/type-inference-generic-instance-creation.html) on "Type Inference for Generic Instance Creation":

> You can replace the type arguments required to invoke the constructor of a generic class with an empty set of type parameters (<>) as long as the compiler can infer the type arguments from the context. This pair of angle brackets is informally called the diamond.

This isn't the only new feature in Java 7 from a language perspective - again, see [the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/language/enhancements.html#javase7) for details.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This sums it up perfectly. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

I dont think its a bad practice, its just a way of giving ease to the programmer.. Consider this

```
Map<List<String>,Map<String,Integer>> superMap = new HashMap<>();
```

the same should have been written as

```
Map<List<String>,Map<String,Integer>> superMap = new HashMap<List<String>,Map<String,Integer>>();
```

in Java 6, where the later generic substitution is redundant

Answer (score 1):

The new format just helps you to save some keystrokes. So in Java 7 when you write

```
List<String> bar = new Arraylist<>();
```

which is considered equal to

```
List<String> foo = new Arraylist<String>();
```

Compiler will automatically infer the types from the left hand side when diamond operator is used.